# Super-annoying indent error (Python)

Tags: python, indentation

the classic unexpected indent error. Here's the relevant code. The question is how do I fix it?

```
    def getNum():
        firstNum = input("Please state what number to start at: ")
        secondNum = input("Please state swhat number to end at: ")
        if countingSubmenu == 3 or countingSubmenu == 4:
            thirdNum = input("Please state what increment you would want to go up by: ")
            return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum
        else:
            return firstNum, secondNum

    if option == 1:
        getNum(firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum)
        for x in range(firstNum, secondNum+1, 1):
            print x
        print "End of test." #def getNum():
```

Comment: Is there a question in our future?  If you don't like Python indentation, either get an IDE that's smarter than you or write with another language.

Comment: Why are you calling a function that takes 0 parameters with 3? The indentation here looks fine, but there's no question being asked so I'm voting to close.

Comment: @user895344 maybe all the lines are indented while they shouldn't

Comment: you should use reindent or Pythontidy before posting

Comment: @duffymo: Real programmers don’t use dumb prosthetics like IDEs to write code.

Answer (score 3):

These three lines are using tabs instead of spaces:

```
            return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum
        else:
            return firstNum, secondNum
```

You can see this pretty easily by attempting to edit the question, the tabs show up with a width of 8 spaces.

Comment: you should use reindent or Pythontidy before posting