# Python indent error. I can't figure out what's wrong here

Tags: python, indentation

I'm using notepad++ which shows the different indents, etc. I keep getting an error code on line 26:

```
return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum
```

Here's the full code. If anyone can see what's going on here, that would be great. I've already killed myself too much over this. I'm sorry if my first question didn't have a specific "question"

```
option = 1
while option !=0:
    print "\n\n\n************MENU************"
    print "1. Counting"
    print "2. Fibbonacci Sequence"
    print "0. GET ME OUTTA HERE!"
    print "*" * 28

    option = input("Please make a selection: ") #counting submenu
    if option == 1:
        print "\n\n*******Counting Submenu*******"
        print "1. Count up by one"
        print "2. Count down by one"
        print "3. Count up by different number"
        print "4. Count down by different number"
        print "*" * 28

        countingSubmenu = input("Please make a selection: ")
        def getNum():
            firstNum = input("Please state what number to start at: ")
            secondNum = input("Please state swhat number to end at: ")
            if countingSubmenu == 3 or countingSubmenu == 4:
                thirdNum = input("Please state what increment you would want to go up by: ")
                return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum
            else:
                return firstNum, secondNum

        if option == 1:
            getNum(firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum)
            for x in range(firstNum, secondNum+1, 1):
                print x
            print "End of test." #def getNum():
```

Comment: Did you change the setting in notepad++ to replace tabs with 4 spaces?  Tabs are registered different in python than spaces.

Comment: That would change it wouldn't it! :) I'll go look! Thanks!

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Comment: It has a few more sentences and still no question. :) @user895344, It'd be nice if you also included what the error was.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Super-annoying indent error (Python)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071777/super-annoying-indent-error-python)

Answer (score 2):

The following three lines use tabs instead of spaces:

```
                return firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum
            else:
                return firstNum, secondNum
```

You can see this fairly easily by attempting to edit the question, you will see tabs show up as 8 spaces and the indentation will be visibly off.

Erase all the whitespace before these lines and indent them again with only spaces and you shouldn't get an indentation error.

Your code still may not be correct, since the function `getNum` does not accept any arguments yet you call it with three.

**edit**: I think that what you are trying to do is get the return values when you call the `getNum` function, to do that you should be calling it like this:

```
firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum = getNum()
```

or...

```
result = getNum()
firstNum, secondNum, thirdNum = result
```

It will probably be easier if you always have `getNum` return the same number of values.  So replace the line `return firstNum, secondNum` with `return firstNum, secondNum, None`.

Comment: Select everything from the start of the line up to the first visible character (in this case the "r" in return), delete it, and then press space until the indentation appears to be in the correct place.

Comment: I meant the "getNum" not accepting arguments. I've been wanting to use the function to reuse and to ask for the numbers over and over again. I just run into Python saying that "variable" isn't defined when the whole point of the function is to define that variable. Would I have to define it before I run the function?

Answer (score 0):

You have three `\t` before that line and you're using four spaces everywhere else (it is also in front of else and the other return which follow). There is a setting in Notepad++ to let you always use spaces for tabs. Because I use it for Python (even though it is only occasionally), this is always turned on for my machines.

Comment: So do I need 8 spaces? I have tab set to 4 space.

Comment: No. That is the width setting, there is another setting which will prevent you from entering `\t` and it will enter four ` ` instead.